# Проблема с сохранением Nullable DateTime значений в БД C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, datetime, null, nhibernate

Использую в проекте на C# *NHibernate*. БД на *MS Access*. У меня почему-то возникает проблема с сохранением значений типа `DateTime`.
Класс сущности:

```
    public class Delivery
    {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    ...
    }
```

Присвоение значения времени (например):

```
    exitDelivery.StartDate = new DateTime(2017,12,2);
```

Сохранение:

```
                using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession(Common.DBpath))
        {
            foreach (var item in deliveries)
            {
                if (item.Id == 0)
                {
                    session.Save(item);
                    session.Evict(item);
                }
                else session.Update(item);

            }
            session.Flush();
        }
```

Причем, само значение времени прекрасно сохраняется в БД, но последняя строка кода вызывает ошибку "Строка не распознана как действительное значение `DateTime`. Если значение времени установить `null`, сохранение происходит без проблем. Если убрать `nullable` у свойства класса, то сохранение также происходит нормально.

Как обойти проблему?

Updated: похоже, что проблема кроется в установке свойству StartDate значения null, но почему-то именно последнему элементу коллекции типа Delivery. Т.е. если у какого элемента коллекции стояла значимая дата и я её меняю на null, то всё в порядке. Но если этот элемент последний, то выскакивает указанная ранее ошибка.

Updated: вот такой код приводит к указанной ошибке:

```
                   for (int i = 0; i < deliveries.Count; i++)
            {
                if (deliveries[i].Id == 0)
                {
                    session.Save(deliveries[i]);
                    session.Evict(deliveries[i]);
                }
                else session.Update(deliveries[i]);                    
            }
    session.Flush();
```

а такой код, не приводит:

```
                   for (int i = 0; i < deliveries.Count; i++)
            {
                if (deliveries[i].Id == 0)
                {
                    session.Save(deliveries[i]);
                    session.Evict(deliveries[i]);
                }
                else session.Update(deliveries[i]);
                session.Flush();
            }
```

Означает ли это, что вызов метода Flush() в цикле сильно снизить производительность кода? Число элементов коллекции не много - до 15.